# <a4j:commandButton> doesn´t start the action

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I need to use the `a4j:commandButton` instead of `h:commandButton` because of its `reRender` option.

When I'm using `h:commandButton`, it works fine (but off course without reRender):

```
<h:commandButton id="save" action="#{bean.save}" value="#{conf.buttonSave}"/>
```

And the same thing using  doesn't (action isn't started even withour reRender option):

```
<a4j:commandButton id="save" action="#{bean.save}" value="#{conf.buttonSave}"/>
```

I've also tried:

```
<h:commandButton id="save" action="#{bean.save}" value="#{conf.buttonSave}">
 <a4j:ajax event="click" reRender="table" />
</h:commandButton>
```

But if I add `a4j:ajax` it the same problem as `a4j:commandButton`, action is not started.

Could you help me?

Comment: There is no `reRender` attribute for the `a4j:commandButton`. I am not familiar with Richfaces, but what is the expected behavior if you omit `reRender`? Does the button behave like a non-ajax button?

Comment: it should re render the datatable based on chenges in datalist.. but problem is that a4j:commandButton doesn't start the action even without reRender option..

Comment: Ok, I think you misinterpreted my comment. I mean there is no `reRender` attribute in your example. What happens if you use the attribute?

Comment: Aha, because main problem is that it doesn't start the action, reRender is secondary problem... I've edited my post

Comment: If there is a problem with ajax you will usually get a javascript error if you click on the button in browser. Check the java console (dev tools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged this JSF 2.0. So you're using JSF 2.0. Just use the JSF 2.0 builtin `<f:ajax>` tag.

```
<h:commandButton id="save" action="#{bean.save}" value="#{conf.buttonSave}">
    <f:ajax render="table" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Note that `<h:dataTable id="table">` must be within the same `<h:form>` the above way. Otherwise you need `render=":table"` instead. Also note that you must have a `<h:head>` instead of `<head>` in the template in order to get all necessary JavaScripts auto-included.